# Notetaking / iPad Pro / Pencil / no Cloud

Tags: note-taking, ipad-app

I have an iPad Pro and an Apple Pencil. I'd like to use them to take notes.

The problem is, I would like to avoid using a cloud service. Furthermore, I would like to be able to export the notes in such a way that I could switch to another app.

These are what I have considered, and why I don't want them:

- Apple Notes feels very limited to me.
- GoodNotes fares well in various review, but it seems, they dropped the no-cloud-sync.
- Evernote is something my colleague uses, but it is cloud-based, and doesn't allow export, among other things.

A search for "note taking apple ipad pro and pencil" gives the following two reviews at the top:

- 9to5mac.com/2016/04/06/…
- michaelhyatt.com/ios-note-taking-apps.html

Both do not mention no-cloud solutions. As mentioned before, GoodNotes removed their no-cloud support.

What other note taking apps are there?

Comment: Currently, Notability is the app of choice, but it does not have handwriting recognition, which does not make the whole note-taking business better than plain old paper.

Comment: Is really nobody using the iPad Pro for notetaking?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Nebo](https://myscript.com/nebo) the handwriting-to-text converter. It allows you to convert handwritten notes to text, and to export  handwritten/converted texts to HTML, PDF, Word, or CSV.

For cloud-sync options, see their [app-support page](https://app-support.myscript.com/support/solutions/folders/16000091803).

It is non-free, though, costs 8.99 € at this time.